# CRV 80km louder engine noise

Tags: engine

Honda CRV 5 years old.  Lately when it gets to 80 km it sounds like it needs another gear, well it's automatic so it finds gears itself, but that's what the noise of the engine sounds like.  It's louder than normal.  Bought new tyres but problem still the same.  Not using more fuel than normal though.  Puzzling.

Comment: Do you have a rev counter?  What is it saying when you drive at 80kmh?

Comment: Does it get quieter again if you drive over 80kmh?

Comment: Have you tried counting the gear changes as you accelerate up to 80?